# How can you change your status in Google Hangouts from Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-hangouts

Is there a way to change your *status* in Google Hangouts from within Gmail?

Comment: There's no status in hangouts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only sign out from Hangouts in Gmail, there is no current way to become invisible like in other messenger applications.

Comment: wow that is so quite the oversight

Answer (score 5):

Actually it's possible to become invisible to some extent. Quoting [Change my status and profile photo](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/6083257?hl=en):

> Invisible: "Invisible status" isn't available in Hangouts, but you can use it by [reverting to Google Chat](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3115176). When you set your Google Chat status to invisible, Hangouts **users will see you as unavailable.**

and

> Tip: If you're busy and you don't want to be notified of text messages or calls, [you can mute notifications](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3111919?&ref_topic=2944922). People who send you messages or invite you to video calls won't be notified that you muted notifications. But **they'll see your profile picture without a green circle**, indicating that you might not be immediately available.