# How can I hide myself (appear offline) in Google Hangouts?

Tags: privacy, google-hangouts

I don't want to be shown as Available (green) in Hangouts even if I am online, or chatting with someone. I don't people to know when I am available. Is it possible to always show myself as if I were offline (white)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you change your status in Google Hangouts from Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/58682/how-can-you-change-your-status-in-google-hangouts-from-gmail)

Comment: The referenced question is too outdated - even if you attempt to follow the 2 answers there, gmail settings no longer give you the option to revert to a previous chat version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling this setting does it:

[image]

You can find it by clicking on the dropdown next to your username on the hangouts window.